# Изменить данные, введённые через форму

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель, которая формирует информацию о сотрудниках.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="ФИО")
date_of_start = models.DateField(verbose_name="Дата оформления")
position = models.ForeignKey("Position", on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Должность")
department = models.ForeignKey("Department", on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Подразделение")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

@property
def days_worked(self):
    days_worked = datetime.now().date() - self.date_of_start
    return days_worked.days
days_worked.fget.short_description = 'Сколько работает'
```

И есть вьюха, которая через форму позволяет загружать новых сотрудников.

```
class Employee_Add(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'manager_employees/employee_add.html'
form_class = EmployeeAddForm

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        messages.success(request, 'Сотрудник загружен успешно')
        Employee.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
        return redirect("base", )
    else:
        messages.success(request, 'Заполните форму корректно')
        form = EmployeeAddForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class EmployeeAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['position'].empty_label = "Выберите должность"
    self.fields['department'].empty_label = "Выберите подразделение"

class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = ["name", "date_of_start", "position", "department"]
    widgets = {
        "name": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        "date_of_start": SelectDateWidget(years=range(2000, 2022)),
        "position": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        "department": forms.Select(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
    }

def clean_title(self):
    title = self.cleaned_data["name"]
    if re.match(r'\d', title):
        raise ValidationError("Имя не должно начинаться с цифры")
    return title
```

Выглядит фронт следующим образом
[image: Выглядит фронт следующим образом]

Вопрос в следующем: как мне реализовать, что бы при нажатии на имя сотрудника был переход на страницу с возможностью изменить его данные. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: можете отправить класс с формой?

Comment: Дополнил описание

Answer (score 0):

```py
form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=obj)
```

Вместо obj прописывай свой объект.
А вообще лучше переписать вьюху через UpdateView:

```py
class Employee_Add(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'manager_employees/employee_add.html'
    form_class = EmployeeAddForm
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=self.get_object())
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, 'Сотрудник загружен успешно')
            form.save()
            return redirect("base", )
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'Заполните форму корректно')
            form = EmployeeAddForm(instance=self.get_object())
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```